# Variável xpath salva em Mongo

Tags: mongodb, scrapy, xpath

Já tentei de diversas formas, mas acredito que estou errando o caminho. Gostaria de salvar o XPATH no Mongodb e importar no item() da function parse. Existe alguma forma de realizar ?

Comment: A sua pergunta [não está muito clara poderia edita-la?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/293012/edit)

Comment: Meu objetivo é salvar o caminho xpath no MongoDB e assim,  quando for usar, importar do banco e realizar o scrapy. Ex: response.xpath('div[@class="product"]').extract(). O problema é que quando vou executar o scrapy, o item() da parse não reconhece e apenas salva o próprio xpath.